# How to make default android Launcher

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

I am trying to create a launcher application and I did it fine.
but there is a problem with my launcher:
When I choose it as default launcher for a device with pressing back button of device my launcher will disappear and last default launcher will appear!
this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AppsListActivity"/>

</application>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
android:name="ah.hathi.simplelauncher.HomeActivity"
android:label="Simple Launcher Home"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
>
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

do it like this hope this will work for you

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358

Comment: try this link will help you more.. remove Launchar from your catagory.

Comment: Thank you, @Zar Saeed, for your answer, but I did this like the website [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358) that you mentioned. but when I want to run the app and set it as default launcher it will set to default launcher, but if I press back button of device my launcher will be minimized ! and the last launcher will be shown.